# 10-08 10:23:40.433: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(10127): Parent view is not a TextView

Tags: android

Hi In don't understand why I get this error: 10-08 10:23:40.433: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(10127): Parent view is not a TextView 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_screen_pass,          
        (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_pass));

        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
```

And the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout_pass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_9" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/approval_icn"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/approval_icon" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

    </ImageView>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/pass_txt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:text="Congratulations you have passed the quiz" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry made it a but unclear the error is 10-08 10:23:40.433: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(10127): Parent view is not a TextView

Comment: **1** - Please **properly indent** your code! **2** - Do you close the LinearLayout, at the end of your xml?

Comment: thanks ill do so, yes I have.

Comment: @Skillie Hi, I am facing this same problem in samsung devices, Please reply how did you solved it

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to the LayoutInflater seems really weird.

`(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_pass)` is a reference to a id within the layout that is to be inflated but the argument is used to pass a root layout to the inflated object. Try just passing `null` as second argument.

Please see the documentation for the [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup))