# 10-08 10:23:40.433: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(10127): Parent view is not a TextView

Tags: java, android

Hi In don't understand why I get this error, Parent view is not a TextView Any help would  be appreciated. I have tried a few things but none seem to work.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast_screen_pass, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.layout_pass));
Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/approval_icn"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/approval_icon" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

</ImageView>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/pass_txt"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp" 
    android:text="Congratulations you have passed the quiz" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The OP asked the same question a few hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252328/10-08-102340-433-e-moreinfohpw-viewgroup10127-parent-view-is-not-a-textvie

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
   View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,
                           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

   ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image);
   image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
   TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);   /// You have to provide textview
   text.setText("Hello! This is a custom toast!");

   Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
   toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
   toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
   toast.setView(layout);
   toast.show();
```

and xml

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:padding="10dp"
     android:background="#DAAA" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a `TextView` to a `Toast` class. But you are providing `Layout`. That is the exception.

If you want to show Custom toast message, You can refer my blog [here](http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/06/dialog-as-toast-message.html).